# Set global relative route for laravel

Tags: laravel

This is the helper function `route()` in laravel

```
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
```

how could i override that function so `$absolute = false` by default?

Comment: `route('name', [], false]);`

Comment: i mean i can use route('name',[]) as normal without set that parameter , is that possible?

Comment: You could write a new helper function that uses `route()` internally. Why, though? What's wrong with the absolute links?

Comment: Yeah, you could even set parameters to null, as it will default to `[]` like so: `route('name', null, false);`

Comment: i force https in cloudflare and when i use route in form the url is http so i cant submit form

Comment: @Derek The `route` helper is part of Laravel. OP doesn't control its defaults.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes he can https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route

Comment: @Derek He wants to change the defaults, i.e. not have to specify `false` every time he uses it. That'd require updating the code in `vendor`, which you can't do.

Comment: @ceejayoz he can control the defaults by *passing* them to the function, as we see in the examples from the documentation: `$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1], false);`

Comment: @spqa You should handle the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header Cloudflare sends correctly, instead of this kludgy workaround. In Apache, you need `SetEnvIf x-forwarded-proto https HTTPS=on` in your VirtualHost config. nginx can do similar.

Comment: @ceejayoz you are right , but that is not a good practice since it is in gitignore

Comment: @Derek OP *clearly* wants a `route('whatever')` call to get `false` by default instead of the usual `true`. OP clearly knows the options are *available*, as he's cited those params in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i force https in cloudflare and when i use route in form the url is http so i cant submit form

Cloudflare sends an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header that should be correctly handled to tell your server it's being accessed over HTTPS.

In Apache, adding this to your VirtualHost should tell Laravel it's being accessed securely and it'll automatically generate the correct URLs:

```
SetEnvIf x-forwarded-proto https HTTPS=on
```